# How do i make an XML-RPC call using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml-rpc

Basically i am trying to use [OpenSubtitles API](http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles) with an Adobe AIR project i am working on. So i want to make an XML RPC call to their server using AJAX. How do i do it ?

Yesterday i tried the same on Python and it was pretty simple.

```
x1 = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc")
response = x1.LogIn("", "", "en", "OS Test User Agent")
```

Now how do i achieve the same in AJAX ?

Answer (score 0):

XML-RPC has a spec you need to follow. You could do that by reading this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC

Or just use this library: http://www.zentus.com/js/xmlrpc.js.html

Comment: I tried using that and that's where i encountered a prob. I want to call this function: LogIn("", "", "en", "OS Test User Agent"). But xmlrpc("http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc", "LogIn", [ "", "", "en", "OS Test User Agent" ], ...) gave me an error in the Params part. What am i doing wrong here ?